# How can I pass id value of just inserted row to another table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table.

```
tags_articles
     tags_id
     articles id

articles
    id
    content
```

`articles` has `id` with `auto_increment`. I want to pass `id` value of `articles` to `tags_articles` table same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after inserting into `articles` and from the *same* database connection, use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
INSERT INTO tags_articles
  (tags_id, articles_id)
VALUES
  (..., LAST_INSERT_ID())
;
```

Note that the driver you are using to access MySQL from your application code may expose a similar method through its API, which one often uses to obtain the ID of a newly inserted record into one's application code (and then subsequently provide that ID in other SQL statements, as required).

Comment: Thanks after checking I'll mark this one as answer. But I want to extend my question.

I have another table named as tags(id, name). So is there way to use it twice. I mean in a one html form it'll pass tags and content but I need tags id and articles id in same time.

Comment: @Imrahil: You'll need to read the ID of each inserted value into your application code, and recall them for the final insertion when ready.  Use your driver's API call if it has one; otherwise one can `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`.